# String manipulation then applying dummy variables to them

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am working on a small project to build a recommendation system. I have the movie's categories column and I would like to apply dummy variables on it.

```
#Here is my data
movie_data.head()

Customer  MovieID  Movie_title       Movie_Category  Movie_cost($)

C1          M1     Gladiator         Drama,Action        3

C2          M2     The Accountant    Drama,Crime         2


#Applying the dummy variables
df_dummies = pd.get_dummies(movie_data['Movie_Category'])
df_dummies.head()

#Here's the output:
Drama,Action   Drama,Crime

1                   0

0                   1

#the desire output:
Drama   Action  Crime

1          1      0

1          0      1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Series.str.get_dummies`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.get_dummies.html):

```
df_dummies = movie_data['Movie_Category'].str.get_dummies(',')
```